# whether pandas.decribe() excludes missing value rows?

Tags: pandas, missing-data, describe

`pandas.describe()` function generate descriptive statistics that summarize the dataset, **excluding NaN values**. But does the exclusion here means that the total count (i.e., rows of a variable) vary or fixed?

For example, I calculate the `mean` by using `describe()` for a df with missing values:

```
varA
 1
 1
 1
 1
 NaN
```

Is the mean = 4/5 or 4/4 here?

And how does it apply to other results in `describe`? For example, the standard deviation, quartiles?

Thanks!

Comment: in you case mean=1 here

Comment: Why would it be `4/5`? It would only make sense if the fifth value were zero. It *ignores* the missing values so the result is `4/4`. It is the same for all operations.

Answer (score 1):

As ayhan pointed out, in the current 0.21 release NaN values are excluded from all summary statistics provided by pandas.DataFrame.describe().

With NaN:

```
data_with_nan = list(range(20)) + [np.NaN]*20
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_with_nan, columns=['col1'])
df.describe()
```

```
           col1
count  20.00000
mean    9.50000
std     5.91608
min     0.00000
25%     4.75000
50%     9.50000
75%    14.25000
max    19.00000
```

Without:

```
data_without_nan = list(range(20))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_without_nan, columns=['col1'])
df.describe()
```

```
           col1
count  20.00000
mean    9.50000
std     5.91608
min     0.00000
25%     4.75000
50%     9.50000
75%    14.25000
max    19.00000
```

Comment: You are probably using an older/buggy version. It calculates quartiles the same way.

Comment: Thank you! That was 0.18. I will update with info from 0.21.